# Moving wordpress site from one domain to another on the same server

Tags: sql-server, wordpress

I've set up a wordpress website on one of our domain names on our dedicated server for testing purposed.
The wordpress site is working brilliant, so now I want to move the wordpress site to another domain name which is also hosted on our dedicated server.

Is it as simple as copying the **root** folder contents that the wordpress site is currently on ... and then pasting that content into the **root** folder of the other domain name?

So just to make things clearer - I want to move the wordpress site from:

Domainname.com to otherdomainname.com
(both domains are hosted on the same server).

... or are there complications involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be that simple - or you can just repoint the domains, which is personally what I would do.

Comment: Cool ...Thanks a lot!! ... no I wouldn't want to involve any redirects with domains because each domain will host different websites eventually.

Comment: I meant after you pointed the prod->test, then you would repoint the test domain to a new blank test location...but the copy should work fine if that is the way you want to go.

Comment: lol ... Thing is I probably wouldn't know how to do that anyway! But I'll remember that in future in-case I need to do something like that. I appreciate your prompt response!!

Comment: Ok, I've done the migration and it works... I just changed the URL under settings... though I the only problem I have is that all my images do not show, why is this? Some show (Like the gallery pics only show)

Comment: Make sure you are using relative paths to your images, not absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes. Backup your contents with the export feature in the Tools section first. Also keep an eye on the wp-config.php. If you didn't hardcode any template links, you should be fine.

Comment: Great advice! Thanks for that! I'll look into the export feature. I'm pretty new with wordpress and although I'm a latecomer at it, am loving wordpress so far!